# Logical database not INSERTING

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have made a service-based database with VS, and added the connection to my project, with VS again. I can edit the database by manually adding the data in the table editor, but when I try to do it programatically, it compiles without errors, and even inserting gives me no errors, but I do not see the data anywhere in the database.

```
SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Users.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
dataConnection.Open();
string query = "INSERT INTO PersonalData(a,b,c,d) VALUES (@a,@b,@c,@d)";
using (SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand(query, dataConnection))
{
    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", textBox1.Text);
    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", textBox2.Text);
    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", textBox3.Text);
    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", textBox4.Text);

    dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
dataConnection.Close();
```

I execute the same exact code on another database that I have in my project, which is a SQLite database, and I can insert without problems, so I'm guessing it has something to do with SQL, but I can't figure it out. How can I insert data from a form into my database?

The code for the table creation is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersonalData] (
[Id]           INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[a] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[b] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[c] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[d] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

);

Comment: Did you step through the code line by line with the debugger attached? Make sure that it takes the proper execution path through your code?

Comment: Yeah, the code executes, the dataCommand is not empty, it has the full command inside it, as well. No exceptions or errors at all.

Comment: Have you tried running this insert in SSMS? Does the table have a trigger or anything like that?

Comment: No, it's a brand new table that I created with VS, it's barebones, the code is all there is to it, even the database is new.

Comment: And it works if you use SSMS?

Comment: I don't have a SQL server, all I have is from VS.

Comment: Click on your database in the solution explorer and ensure you have the `copy to output` set to **never copy** or **copy if newer**. This may just be an issue with the database being rewritten from the template in the project folder.

Comment: if I set it to never copy, I get the following exception: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file "Filepath" failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.'`

I had it on copy if newer previously, but it didn't work either.

Comment: So does Users.mdf appear in your Server Explorer? If so, expand it and right click on your personaldata table and click Show Table Data. If it's blank, close the window, run and execute your code and show table data again. If there's no data then the only thing I can think to ask is, do you have this code inside a try...catch that you might be burying an exception with? EDIT: I see you already stated this is all the code, so where exactly does this code reside?

Comment: The code is on a button click event. 
Also, I can add stuff to the table in the VS server explorer, it works just fine, but I can't seem to insert it with the code above.

Comment: Hilight Users.mdf in the server explorer and then in the properties window double-click the Connection String property. This will hilight the connection string. right click on the actual connection string that's hilight and copy. Paste that into your code window and compare it with what you have. It's almost like you're not talking to the same datafile.

Comment: I have the full path to the .mdf file in the connection string, but in the code, I use `|DataDirectory|`. The one in the ConnectionString is: `AttachDbFilename=C:\..\ProjectName\Users.mdf`. As in, I don't have it pointed to the /bin/ of my project. I do not know where exactly the DataDirectory is pointing.

Comment: for testing purposes, copy the connection string from the users.mdf property to your connectionstring in the code and try. I think you're dealing with a copy that's probably located inside your AppData folder of your user profile in windows.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, and as much I would like to continue debugging this, it's simply not feasible, so I instead opted to use SQLite... Also, if I copy/paste the path, wouldn't that make it worse, since the project would only work on my PC?